# Find which character occurs the greatest number of times in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

With Oracle SQL query, can we do the following?

```
      Input       Output
    'aaaabcd' --->  'a'
    '0001001' --->  '0'
```

That is, find the character which is occurring the greatest number of times in the string?

Comment: Are all strings of the same length (7)? What if 'aaabbbi'?

Comment: What should be the output if you have more than one max occurences?

Comment: Check this asktom link https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:55423584511523

Comment: Is PLSQL an Option? Because writing a function in PLSQL and then using it in the SELECT Query is the most sensible approach to this...

Comment: @jarlh : No. All strings may not be of same length. In case of 'aaabbbi' output can be 'a' or 'b'. Both are valid outputs in this case. Actually in my case, more than one max occurrence will not happen. Still for sake of clarity, we will put some condition to filter out one. I should have mentioned these things. Apologies.

Comment: @LalitKumarB : Same as my previous comment. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Falco : well, currently I am not using PL/SQL and dependent on SQL query solely. But its not a closed window. Solutions with PL/SQL are also welcome. Only thing is I won't be able to use that right now. But for knowledge purpose always a Yes.

Comment: If anyone looking into this runs into performance issues, use PL/SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through the use of `CONNECT BY`. A bit complicated, though:

```
SELECT xchar, xcount FROM (
    SELECT xchar, COUNT(*) AS xcount, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT SUBSTR('aaaabcd', LEVEL, 1) AS xchar
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('aaaabcd')
   ) GROUP BY xchar
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

What we do in the innermost query is break the string into its individual characters. Then we just get the `COUNT()` grouped by the character, and use `RANK()` to find the max (note that this will return more than one result if there is a tie for the most frequently occurring character).

The above query returns both the character appearing most often and the number of times it appears.

If you have a table of multiple strings, then you'll want to do something like the following:

```
WITH strlen AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS strind
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
)
SELECT id, xchar, xcount FROM (
    SELECT id, xchar, COUNT(*) AS xcount, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT s.id, SUBSTR(s.str, sl.strind, 1) AS xchar
          FROM strings s, strlen sl
         WHERE LENGTH(s.str) >= sl.strind
   ) GROUP BY id, xchar
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

where `30` is a magic number that is equal to the length of your longest string, or greater. [**See SQL Fiddle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00a95/7) Alternately, you could do the following to avoid the magic number:

```
WITH strlen AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS strind
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT MAX(LENGTH(str)) FROM strings )
)
SELECT id, xchar, xcount FROM (
    SELECT id, xchar, COUNT(*) AS xcount, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT s.id, SUBSTR(s.str, sl.strind, 1) AS xchar
          FROM strings s, strlen sl
         WHERE LENGTH(s.str) >= sl.strind
   ) GROUP BY id, xchar
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00a95/8)

Comment: Yeah... you can do all kinds of crazy stunts with CONNECT BY... But really? Can't you just use PLSQL, write a nice little readable function?

Comment: If I can do it in SQL then I'd rather not do it in PLSQL.

Comment: Why would you do that? This is not a Set-Operation, but a sequential one... PLSQL is most likely more readable, easily reusable in larger queries and probably more efficient. If you want this frequency for 2 columns on a table which match certain criteria, the SQL-Solution will be nearly unreadable and maybe even mess up the query plan... The function is also deterministic so will be cached for rows with same content...

Comment: Sorry - I just did a check over 10K rows with your solution on 11g with fixed Length 30 and it took 45 seconds. The PLSQL-approach finished in 2 seconds with the same result... please give PLSQL a chance where it can shine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way - assuming you want to show all rows that have the highest number of characters per string:

```
with sample_data as (select 'aaaabcd' str from dual union all
                     select '0001001' str from dual union all
                     select '11002' str from dual),
         pivoted as (select str, substr(str, level, 1) letter
                     from   sample_data
                     connect by level <= length(str)
                                and prior str = str
                                and prior dbms_random.value is not null),
             grp as (select str, letter, count(*) cnt
                     from   pivoted
                     group by str, letter),
          ranked as (select str,
                            letter,
                            dense_rank() over (partition by str order by cnt desc) dr
                     from   grp)
select str, letter
from   ranked
where  dr = 1;

STR     LETTER
------- ------
0001001 0     
11002   1     
11002   0     
aaaabcd a
```

If you wanted to only show one of the letters in the event of a tie, change the `dense_rank()` in the query above for a `row_number`.

If you wanted to show all tied letters in a single row (e.g. comma separated) then use listagg in the final query to group the rows into one.

Answer (score 1):

One Option is to do it in PL/SQL. - Why PLSQL?

PLSQL is most likely more readable, easily reusable in larger queries and probably more efficient. If you want this frequency for 2 columns on a table which match certain criteria, the SQL-Solution will be nearly unreadable and maybe even mess up the query plan... The function is also deterministic so will be cached for rows with same content...

Also you can use this function for virtual-Columns or function based indexes.

A quick (probably not very reliable) benchmark comparing PLSQL to the proposed CONNECT BY solutions over 10K rows on a 11g DB showed a runtime of about 40 seconds for CONNECT BY and 2 seconds for PLSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION get_most_freq_char( p_input VARCHAR2 )
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS  
  TYPE t_charcount IS TABLE OF SIMPLE_INTEGER
                      INDEX BY VARCHAR2(1);
  l_map      t_charcount;
  l_value    VARCHAR2(1);
  l_maxchar  VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH( p_input )
  LOOP
    l_value := SUBSTR( p_input, i ,1 );

    l_map( l_value ) := CASE WHEN l_map.EXISTS( l_value )
                             THEN l_map( l_value ) + 1
                             ELSE 1 END;

    IF l_maxchar IS NULL OR l_map( l_value ) > l_map( l_maxchar )
    THEN
      l_maxchar := l_value;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  RETURN l_maxchar;
END;
/

SELECT get_most_freq_char( 'abcdeffffffbbbaaaaaa' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all great answers. Assuming you have table similar to this:

```
FULL_STRING
-----------
0001230
aaaabcd
bbbbcdef


SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT full_str
      , str max_char_in_string
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY full_str ORDER BY full_str) rno
   FROM
   (
    SELECT distinct full_str, SUBSTR(full_str, LEVEL, 1) AS str
      FROM drop_tab
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(full_str)
   ORDER BY 1
   )
 ORDER BY 3, 1
 )
WHERE rno = 1
/

FULL_STRING MAX_CHAR RNO
-------------------------
0001230      0       1
aaaabcd      a       1
bbbbcdef     b       1
```